# Empty textfield value after onChange using selectize

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I have a hybrid text field & dropdown inputs on my code using selectize. I want that upon change of value the text field will be emptied. How do I do these? Below is my code.

```
var $select =  $('#prod_search').selectize({
                persist: false,
                maxItems: 1,
                valueField: 'stock_no',
                searchField: ['name', 'barcode', 'stock_no'],
                onChange: function(value) {
                    search_prod(value);
                    //insert code that empties the text field//
                },
                options: products_list,
                render: {
                    item: function(item, escape) {
                        return '<div>' +
                            (item.name ? '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' : '') +
                        '</div>';
                    },
                    option: function(item, escape) {
                        var label = item.stock_no + ' - ' + item.name || item.stock_no;
                        var caption = item.name ? item.stock_no : null;
                        return '<div>' + '<span class="">' + escape(label) + '</span>' + '</div>';
                    }
                }
});
```

Comment: `$(textAreaSelector).val('');`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `clear(true)` (see [API reference](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md)).